# Configuring Views into Features

Tags: 7, views, features

I have inherited a complex website which has the Features and Views module installed.
I can configure a Feature to include a View as you would expect.

However, I'm putting together a private website which also has Views and Features installed.
My problem is Views does not appear as an option to select data from when configuring the Feature.

**Is there a setting or module which is responsibly for exposing Views in Feature create/edit mode ????**

The [image](https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/Features2.png) on the Feature project page seems to suggest Views should be there by default.

Any help, please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps all the available views have been added to other features? Try enabling the checkbox "Allow conflicts to be added" in the 'Advanced Options' section of the 'Create' page. If you can see the views then, it means they are already assigned to other features.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but the site is entirely fresh and there are no pre-existing features with any packaged views

Comment: Are there views available to be added? Perhaps all the available views are disabled? Have you created a new view and checked to see whether it is available?

Comment: Yes, there are 4 views. I've even been enabling some of the default views but Features still won't show a Views interface

Comment: Sorry to belabour this point, but when you say there are 4 views, are these default views provided by Drupal or views you created yourself?  If you enable 'Allow conflicts to be added', do you see any views then?

Comment: Hey Frank, you were right. I just realized I wasn't patient enough to see the Views interface when I checked the "allow conflicts" box.                                          Views now displays but there is literally no conflict with any other feature

Comment: While "allow conflicts" allows views to display, selecting a view and building it into the feature does not work. The package refuses to include the views config

Comment: Features won't list a view for inclusion if it already exists in code. If you create a brand-new view of your own, does it appear as a candidate for inclusion in Features?

Comment: Yes, a simple new view is listed in the views component area. But the issue is that there were no conflicts between any of the features. None of those features even had views configured. I switched off 2 of the 3 features, to eliminate any "conflicts" but Views still does not show up in the last surviving feature ?!?!??!

Comment: Existence of a conflict is one reason why a view might not be listed for inclusion. Existence of the view in code is another reason. When neither of those conditions apply (i.e. you created a new view), your view is listed. If there are no conflicts, it stands to reason all the other views on your site are in code. If they are not in code via features, most likely they are are in code via modules.

Comment: You have been right all along. I appreciate all your help. Thank you